# Why is setState triggering 2 FutureBuilder runs?

Tags: sql, flutter, setstate, state-management, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm using a `FutureBuilder` to build a list of items from a future from database calls.
For some reason, when I call `setState()` the `FutureBuilder` runs twice which is problematic.
I've made a simplified version of my code to illustrate the issue:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  futureIng = db.getIngredients();
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      getButton(),
      getDeleteButton(),
      FutureBuilder<List<IngredientSql>>(
        future: futureIng,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<IngredientSql>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
            if (snapshot.data.isEmpty) {
              return Text("Nothing yet", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white));
            }
            return Text(getList(snapshot.data));
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    ],
  );
}
}

void insertIngredient() {
Future<bool> success = db.insertIngredient("banana2"));
success.then((success) {
  if (success) {
    setState(() {
      futureIng = db.getIngredients();
    });
});


}

void deleteIngredient() {
var future = db.deleteIngredient("banana2");
future.then((value) {
  futureIng = db.getIngredients();
  futureIng.then((value) {
    setState(() {
      print("asd");
    });
  });
});


}
```

Pressing the `getButton()` calls `insertIngredient()` and pressing the `getDeleteButton()` calls `deleteIngredient()`.

So first I insert the "banana2" ingredient, then I press delete to remove it. As you can see in the `deleteIngredient()` function, the item is removed, then I update the future and call `setState()` to rebuild the output text. HOWEVER, `FutureBuilder` is now called 2 times, once where nothing has happened (banana2 is still output) and then immediately again and it is removed.

What is going on here?

Comment: maybe u can make a minimum reproducible example which community can run?

Answer (score 0):

I think it goes like this :
The first time the futurebuilder is rebuilt as a widget which has a value that has changed, so the setState() method make it rebuild.
The second time, it is because the FutureBuilder rebuilts himself, because you got the value from the AsyncSnapshot futureIng, and it is the 'normal' rebuild that you would expect.

So the build that you don't want to have is caused by the fact that the instance of futureIng is changed and the Widget FutureBuilder rebuilds as a normal widget would do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% sure why it is run twice, but the first "incorrect" run, connectionstate is waiting, and it is "done" the second "correct" run. So i fixed my problem with a simple if statement.